# Why do my icons get splattered over if used more than once in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See this image. [image]

Everything works fine when I use one icon but when I do this, things go beserk, i.e using more than once:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home <i class="icon-home icon-white"></a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jobs">Jobs</a></li>
              <li><a style="color:orange;" href="logout">Logout <i class="icon-off icon-white"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: You have an unclosed `i` tag in the first line.

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing your first icon tag so your other `li` elements are getting the image as well:

```
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home <i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks I think I figured it out before. Thanks anyway

Comment: @AliGajani noticed, a user on the comments posted a couple of minutes before me. Can you post your results in the form of an answer and approve that by ticking the green checkmark to the side? That way we can close this thread and it can later help other posters with the same issue.